# Select and switch items in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with items of points (latitude and longitude) and i want to select the 3 closest by default and let the user switch any of those 3 points with any other point in the list (the main purpose of 3 points is for spacial interpolation).
Is this possible or how can i make something similar?

Example:

The user is in position (lat, lon).
The `ListView` have the items (x1, y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4), ...

The app select the 3 closest items of user position by default, for example the 3 first items. And now the user must be able to switch for example (x1,y1) with (x4,y4).

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't understand your question. You want to select three items from a `ListView`?

Comment: Yes. The app have to select three items by default and the user can swich the selected by default with any other item.

Comment: Where is your effort? Show us some code. Of course it is possible, arrayadapter (google an example) + Pythagoras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my solution. I`ve tried to create the answer of what you need. This is simple and easy.

Here is the code:

### Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private final Context context;
public final ArrayList<PointItem> pointItems;

private int firstActivePointPosition;
private int secondActivePointPosition;
private int thirdActivePointPosition;

private int clickCounter;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<PointItem> pointItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.pointItems = pointItems;

    //Default points
    this.pointItems.get(0).isChecked = true;
    this.pointItems.get(1).isChecked = true;
    this.pointItems.get(2).isChecked = true;

    this.firstActivePointPosition = 0;
    this.secondActivePointPosition = 1;
    this.thirdActivePointPosition = 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pointItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pointItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public void checkActivePosition(int position) {
    if (!this.pointItems.get(position).isChecked) {
        this.pointItems.get(position).isChecked = true;

        if (clickCounter == 0) {
            this.pointItems.get(this.firstActivePointPosition).isChecked = false;
            this.firstActivePointPosition = position;
        } else if (clickCounter == 1) {
            this.pointItems.get(this.secondActivePointPosition).isChecked = false;
            this.secondActivePointPosition = position;
        } else if (clickCounter == 2) {
            this.pointItems.get(this.thirdActivePointPosition).isChecked = false;
            this.thirdActivePointPosition = position;

            this.clickCounter = -1;
        }

        this.clickCounter++;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        PointItem pointItem = (PointItem) getItem(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.point_item_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.title.setText(pointItem.title);

        if (pointItem.isChecked) {
            viewHolder.title.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else {
            viewHolder.title.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        }
    }

    public static class PointItem {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public String title;

        public boolean isChecked;

        public PointItem(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            this.title = String.format("(%d, %d)", this.x, this.y);
        }
    }
}
```

### Initialize

```
ArrayList<Adapter.PointItem> pointItems = new ArrayList<>();
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(0, 0));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(1, 1));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(2, 2));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(3, 3));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(4, 4));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(5, 5));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(6, 6));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(7, 7));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(8, 8));
        pointItems.add(new Adapter.PointItem(9, 9));

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getBaseContext(), pointItems);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Adapter adapter = (Adapter) parent.getAdapter();
                adapter.checkActivePosition(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That only let the user have 3 consecutive items selected and i want to be able to really switch items. For example when user have (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) if he select (0,0) and (9,9) the items are switched and the result must be (9,9), (1,1), (2,2).

Comment: Ok. This is even easier that i gonna think. Wait for solution.

Comment: Also the question. When to switch second and third items?

Comment: The user can choose any of the selected items and switch with any of the unselected.

Comment: You hve implemented something like a FIFO so I can only switch with the "older" item, but it works. If i need I can change it. Thanks.

Comment: Its easy to understand.